# Can the Dialogflow Client API (NodeJS) work in a stateless manner?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am looking at developing a solution with Dialogflow, where the User Interface events (e.g. Typed user input) are going to arrive as http REST events.

The problem with this is that the Dialogflow Client API (Note: This is NOT THE SAME THING as the fulfilment API), looks like it is stateful: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow

(... But I could be wrong on that...)

And stateful is hard in most (all?) modern serverless paradigms that any sane person is probably using. Mainly - There is no gaurantee that subsequent events will arrive at the same run-time instance.

It's a bit infuriating that although many examples are supplied at the repo above, none of them look like realistic (but small) applications, handling multi-session, multi-turn (even 2-3 turns) user input.

**Is the idea that any run-time instance could/would call `new dialogflow.SessionsClient();` just once PER RUNTIME initialisation (NOT per session) to initialise the API, and then everything else is done via like `await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);` ???**

Now that I've typed this, I am pretty confident that is right. But if anyone could confirm it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying Dialogflow Session API itself is stateless - any statefull decisions that are made must be included in your call to `detectIntent`. The JavaScript library reflects this stateless scenario as well.

The `SessionsClient` constructor sets up the connection and authentication information, but does not maintain any other *conversational* state. So you can use the same object to manage multiple conversations.

Note that this still means *you* need to maintain conversational state (the session id, the values and lifespans returned in contexts, etc) in order to pass it to `detectIntent` as part of the request.

Comment: Hello, and thanks @Prisoner! That totally makes sense now. Really just a lack of practical documentation I daresay!